# lifetime around async and stream

Tags: rust, async-await, stream, lifetime, rust-2018

I am trying to make a function that consumes `Stream` and truncate it when there are `max_consecutive_fails` consecutive fails. However, things didn't work well(E0495). I changed `Stream`s to `Iterator`s (and removed `async`s) and it simply worked. Why does this happen? How can I refactor this code (to work)?

```rust
use futures::stream::Stream;
pub fn max_fail<'a, T>(stream : impl Stream<Item = Option<T>> +'a , max_consecutive_fails: usize) -> impl Stream +'a where T : 'a
{
    use futures::stream::StreamExt;
    let mut consecutive_fails = 0;
    stream.take_while(move |x| async {
        if x.is_some(){
            consecutive_fails = 0;
            true
        }
        else{
            consecutive_fails += 1;
            consecutive_fails != max_consecutive_fails
        }
    })
}
```

The below one is the minimized example I tried to point out what the problem is, but I still wasn't able to understand the rustc error message.

```rust
use futures::stream::Stream;
pub fn minified_example<'a>(stream: impl Stream<Item = bool> + 'a) -> impl Stream + 'a
{
    use futures::stream::StreamExt;
    stream.take_while( |x| async { *x })
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from including "thanks" or similar in your question. See here for more explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts , and here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 2):

Async blocks (`async { ... }`) are similar to closures in the way they capture their environment. By default, every use of a variable from the other scope is by reference, which means the `impl core::future::Future` created by the block cannot outlive the variables it captures.

You need to move `x` into the block with `async move { ... }` (Just like with closures)

Answer (score 0):

So `Future` captures variable, and the compiler isn't smart enough to remove unnecessary captures, and what one should do is explicitly disentangle the captures with separate async block.

```rust
use futures::stream::Stream;
pub fn max_fail<'a, T>(
    stream: impl Stream<Item = Option<T>> + 'a,
    max_consecutive_fails: usize,
) -> impl Stream + 'a
where
    T: 'a,
{
    use futures::stream::StreamExt;
    let mut consecutive_fails = 0;
    stream.take_while(move |x| {
        let t = if x.is_some() {
            consecutive_fails = 0;
            true
        } else {
            consecutive_fails += 1;
            consecutive_fails != max_consecutive_fails
        };
        return async move { t };
    })
}
```