# Changing a member while in an async stream

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct with a member. The implementation returns an async stream which changes this member on a specific event (in the example on each).

This fails with a lifetime error, which is understandable, since the struct itself is not necessarily in the same lifetime as the `map` in the stream. it sounds similar to [lifetime around async and stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578878/lifetime-around-async-and-stream), but I am not sure if it is related.

```rust
use async_std::pin::Pin;
use futures::{Stream, StreamExt};
use std::time::Duration;

struct StreamProvider {
    value: u16,
}

impl StreamProvider {
    fn returnastream(self: &mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = i32>>> {
        return async_std::stream::interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
            .map(|_| {
                // change a value of Self within the stream
                self.value = self.value + 1;
                1
            })
            .boxed();
    }
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut object = StreamProvider { value: 1 };

    let mut worx = object.returnastream();
    // subscribing to the items
    while let item = worx.next().await {
        match item {
            Some(value) => println!("{}", value),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3.6"
async-std = { version = "1.6.5", features = ["attributes", "unstable"] }
```

The Error message:

```
/Users/andre/.cargo/bin/cargo run --color=always --package traittest --bin traittest
   Compiling traittest v0.1.0 (/Users/andre/repos/traittest)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
20 |         }).boxed();
   |            ^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 14:3...
  --> src/main.rs:14:3
   |
14 | /   fn returnastream(self: &mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item=i32>>> {
15 | |     return async_std::stream::interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
16 | |         .map(|_| {
17 | |           // change a value of Self within the stream
...  |
20 | |         }).boxed();
21 | |   }
   | |___^
note: ...so that the type `futures_util::stream::stream::map::Map<async_std::stream::interval::Interval, [closure@src/main.rs:16:14: 20:10 self:&mut &mut StreamProvider]>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
20 |         }).boxed();
   |            ^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/main.rs:15:12
   |
15 |       return async_std::stream::interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
   |  ____________^
16 | |         .map(|_| {
17 | |           // change a value of Self within the stream
18 | |           self.value = self.value + 1;
19 | |           1
20 | |         }).boxed();
   | |__________________^
   = note: expected  `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = i32> + 'static)>>`
              found  `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = i32>>>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: You need to use synchonisation primitives, for example `Arc` and `Mutex`, in order to access and mutate values that are owned by another thread.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I added the error message.

Comment: What version of Rust are you using? Rust 1.47.0 produces a completely different error message for the code that you've posted here.

Comment: Have been using 1.44.0 just updated to 1.47.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Peter Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493729/peter-hall):

> You need to use synchonisation primitives, for example `Arc` and `Mutex`, in order to access and mutate values that are owned by another thread.

This was the link I missed. Here's the result:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use async_std::pin::Pin;
use futures::{Stream, StreamExt};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct StreamProvider {
    value: Arc<Mutex<u16>>,
}

impl StreamProvider {
    fn returnastream(self: &mut Self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = i32>>> {
        let v = self.value.clone();
        return async_std::stream::interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
            .map(move |_| {
                let mut a = v.lock().unwrap();
                // change a value of Self within the stream
                *a += 1;
                1
            })
            .boxed();
    }
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut object = StreamProvider {
        value: Arc::new(Mutex::new(1)),
    };

    let mut worx = object.returnastream();
    // subscribing to the items
    while let item = worx.next().await {
        match item {
            Some(_) => println!("{}", object.value.lock().unwrap()),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3.6"
async-std = { version = "1.6.5", features = ["attributes", "unstable"] }
```